# Error passing a method name as argument in a class method

Tags: python

Well I am trying to do this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def method1(self):
        print "method1"
    def method2(self):
        print "method2"        

class Fo1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = Foo()
    def classMethod(self, selection):
        self.a.selection()

A = Fo1()
A.classified('method2')
```

I got this error:

`--> AttributeError: 'Fo1' object has no attribute 'selection'`

I don't want to use this (seems to me, more coding):

```
 def classified(self,selection):
    if selection == "method1": self.a.method1()
    elif selection == "method2": self.a.method2()
```

How should I code the method so that I can pass the method name as an argument?
Thanks!

Comment: `getattr(self.a, selection)()`.

Comment: There's rarely a reason to actually do this. You can pass a reference to a method directly: `A.classMethod(Foo.method2)`

Comment: you're calling classified where you seem to mean to be calling classMethod. that is, you're using classMethod and classified interchangeably. pick one name.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `getattr` to do this, e.g.

```
def classMethod(self, selection):
    getattr(self.a, selection)()
```

[getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) takes an object an attribute name and returns the attribute, which you can then call.